# How to escape double quotes when using Rscript function in Bash

Tags: r, bash, tinytex

How can I escape double quotes to run this code block on the command line? The part of the code that is problematic is `` paste('! LaTeX Error: File', paste0("`", x, "'.sty'"), 'not found.')) ``.

```bash
Rscript \
  -e "biosketch_pkgs <- list('microtype', 'tabu', 'ulem', 'enumitem', 'titlesec')" \
  -e "lapply(biosketch_pkgs, function (x) {tinytex::parse_install(text=paste('! LaTeX Error: File', paste0("`", x, "'.sty'"), 'not found.'))})"
```

I have tried to escape the double quote using the below but it returns `unexpected EOF while looking for matching` ''`

```bash
Rscript \
  -e "biosketch_pkgs <- list('microtype', 'tabu', 'ulem', 'enumitem', 'titlesec')" \
  -e "lapply(biosketch_pkgs, function (x) {tinytex::parse_install(text=paste('! LaTeX Error: File', paste0("\`"\, x, "\'.sty'"\), 'not found.'))})"
```

Comment: You need to put backslashes **before** double quotes to escape them, not after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of worrying about how to escape specific strings, think about handling in them a way that avoids the need to do any escaping at all. Running `Rscript -` tells Rscript to read the source code to run on stdin, while `<<'EOF'` makes all content up to the next line containing only `EOF` be fed on stdin. (You can replace the characters `EOF` with any other sigil you choose, but it's important that this sigil be quoted or escaped to instruct the shell not to modify the content in any way).

```bash
Rscript - <<'EOF'
  biosketch_pkgs <- list('microtype', 'tabu', 'ulem', 'enumitem', 'titlesec')
  lapply(biosketch_pkgs, function (x) {
    tinytex::parse_install(text=paste('! LaTeX Error: File',
                                      paste0("`", x, "'.sty'"),
                                      'not found.'))
  })
EOF
```

If you *did* have a compelling reason to use `Rscript -e`, though, a correct escaping would put backslashes before backticks, double quotes, or other syntax that has meaning to the shell within a double-quoted string, as follows:

```bash
Rscript \
  -e "biosketch_pkgs <- list('microtype', 'tabu', 'ulem', 'enumitem', 'titlesec')" \
  -e "lapply(biosketch_pkgs, function (x) {tinytex::parse_install(text=paste('! LaTeX Error: File', paste0(\"\`\", x, \"'.sty'\"), 'not found.'))})"
```

Comment: "think about handling in them a way that avoids the need to do any escaping" yes, this.   An alternative would be to provide the script via file (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/Rscript)

Comment: Is this code for cmd or for bash/batch file?

Comment: @onyambu, this is for bash, not cmd or batch.